# Too many files open in java

Tags: java, encryption, key-pair

I have functionality in my web application running on tomcat where I need to decrypt encrypted text using jks file. I am using following code. From the below code I get RSAPrivateKey which used for decryption.

```
PathResource containerResources = new PathResource(Paths.get(filename);
KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
        containerResources, "abcd".toCharArray());
KeyPair keypair = keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("someurl.com");
return keypair;
```

When I run this code there are multiple files getting open. I have checked this using `lsof` command. I have increased the ulimit open file limit but that is temporary solution.
Is there any way to close these open files?

Comment: This is spring, right? Sounds like a bug that was fixed there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/1708. Maybe you just need to update?

Comment: @OmairMajid Do I need to upgrade spring-security-oauth2 version in my pom.xml ?

Comment: Yes. Depending on whether you are using 2.0 (update to 2.0.19 or later), 2.1 (upgrade to 2.1.6 or later), or 2.2 (upgrade to 2.2.6 or later).

Comment: @OmairMajid I am using 2.3.3.RELEASE version.